# Ruby Prepend Module - how to prepend module to the beginning of ancestors array from Parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code like this:

```
module ModuleToPrepend
  def perform(*args)
    puts args
    super
  end
end

class Base
  prepend ModuleToPrepend
end

class Child < Base
  def perform(*args)
    do_something(args)
  end
end
```

I'm looking for a solution to print method arguments before every `Child.new.perform` call. I want to prepend a module `ModuleToPrepend` to the beginning of the ancestors list inside a class `Base`. I don't want to prepend it in a class `Child` because there are hundreds of them.

My code returns this: `Child.ancestrors #=> [Child, ModuleToPrepend, Base]`
I want this: `Child.ancestrors #=> [ModuleToPrepend, Child, Base]`

Can it be done in ruby?

Comment: Where do you expect the relation between `Child` and `Base` to come from?

Comment: @sawa sorry, it inherits from base, updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if there are any side-effects of this (if anyone, please enlighten me) but the following should work:

```
module ModuleToPrepend
  def perform(*args)
    puts 'ModuleToPrepend#perform'
    puts args
    super
  end
end

class Base
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    puts 'Base.inherited'
    subclass.prepend(ModuleToPrepend) if subclass.superclass == Base
    super
  end
end

class Child < Base
  def perform(*args)
    puts 'Child#perform'
  end
end
# => Base.inherited

class Subchild < Child
  def perform(*args)
    puts 'Subchild#perform'
    super
  end
end
# => Base.inherited

puts Child.ancestors
# => [ModuleToPrepend, Child, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

child = Child.new
child.perform('arg1', 'arg2')
# => ModuleToPrepend#perform
# => [arg1, arg2]
# => Child#perform

puts Subchild.ancestors
# => [Subchild, ModuleToPrepend, Child, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

subchild = Subchild.new
subchild.perform('arg1', 'arg2')
# => Subchild#perform
# => ModuleToPrepend#perform
# => [arg1, arg2]
# => Child#perform
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great solution.

Comment: Great! No problem! :)

Comment: I found one side effect. If I have some other class that inherits from `Child` the ancestors list looks like: `[ModuleToPrepend, ChildOfChild, ModuleToPrepend, Child, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` so this puts is evaluated two times.

Comment: Hmm. I see. Okay, let's enforce a condition to only prepend to "immediate subclass" of `Base`. See my updated answer.